# how to make the nav-bar fixed and on top of the page and not overlapable

Tags: css, html

so I'm still a beginner and my question may sound silly to others ,however, I need to fix this problem so this is my `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <div id="header">
          <ul id="nav">
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">about</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Our products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id = "p">
        <p>Libero cupiditate tempore autem animi iusto, expedita neque voluptatibus dolor sequi quia nihil quam magnam, magni praesentium nam aut ipsum soluta nulla et, eum sed? Explicabo modi similique nobis nesciunt!</p>
        <p>Itaque, corrupti quae corporis excepturi eum vero, rem aliquam dolorem, adipisci maxime deleniti. Dicta beatae voluptatum maiores nesciunt, ducimus eveniet. Reprehenderit doloremque, laboriosam repellat rerum adipisci dolores quia sapiente cupiditate!</p>
        <p>Voluptatibus tenetur sit tempore inventore optio nihil nostrum sapiente neque, odio ipsa atque? Tenetur earum voluptatum omnis dignissimos dolores reprehenderit sint quo ducimus, cumque inventore laboriosam asperiores laborum nemo perferendis.</p>
        <p>Minima ab blanditiis, rerum voluptas dicta ducimus, voluptates itaque reprehenderit numquam mollitia possimus quod amet harum non eius perferendis iste saepe rem maiores est. Similique minus consequatur reiciendis voluptatem quibusdam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni minus aspernatur ullam eligendi illum laboriosam, quas omnis facilis voluptatum quis iste ipsam ut aliquam praesentium dolorem. Fugit assumenda nobis distinctio.</p>
    </div>
<footer> <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
    <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
    Personal Email</a>.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

the nav-bar over laps with the paragraphs as you notice I made the position of `#header` `fixed`and I made `#first top:0;` 
I can't figure out the problem and if I were to make a sidebar how to prevent it from overlapping with other elements or even how to prevent elements from overlapping with other elements?

```
 #first{
    top:0;
}
#header{
    position: fixed;

}
#nav{

        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: lightcoral;

        border: lightcoral solid;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;

}
#nav li{
    float: left;
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
}

#nav li a {

    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {

    color: dimgray;

}


#nav li:hover {
    border: (214, 20, 124) solid;
    background-color:rgb(214, 20, 124);
    color: dimgray;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
#nav li:last-child{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#first{
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
}
#header{
    position: fixed;
    width:98%;
}
#nav{

        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: lightcoral;
        width:100%;

        border: lightcoral solid;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;

}
#nav li{
    float: left;
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
}

#nav li a {

    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {

    color: dimgray;

}


#nav li:hover {
    border: (214, 20, 124) solid;
    background-color:rgb(214, 20, 124);
    color: dimgray;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
#nav li:last-child{
    float: right;
}
#p{
    margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <div id="header">
          <ul id="nav">
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">about</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="head"><a href="http://">Our products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id = "p">
        <p>Libero cupiditate tempore autem animi iusto, expedita neque voluptatibus dolor sequi quia nihil quam magnam, magni praesentium nam aut ipsum soluta nulla et, eum sed? Explicabo modi similique nobis nesciunt!</p>
        <p>Itaque, corrupti quae corporis excepturi eum vero, rem aliquam dolorem, adipisci maxime deleniti. Dicta beatae voluptatum maiores nesciunt, ducimus eveniet. Reprehenderit doloremque, laboriosam repellat rerum adipisci dolores quia sapiente cupiditate!</p>
        <p>Voluptatibus tenetur sit tempore inventore optio nihil nostrum sapiente neque, odio ipsa atque? Tenetur earum voluptatum omnis dignissimos dolores reprehenderit sint quo ducimus, cumque inventore laboriosam asperiores laborum nemo perferendis.</p>
        <p>Minima ab blanditiis, rerum voluptas dicta ducimus, voluptates itaque reprehenderit numquam mollitia possimus quod amet harum non eius perferendis iste saepe rem maiores est. Similique minus consequatur reiciendis voluptatem quibusdam.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni minus aspernatur ullam eligendi illum laboriosam, quas omnis facilis voluptatum quis iste ipsam ut aliquam praesentium dolorem. Fugit assumenda nobis distinctio.</p>
    </div>
<footer> <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
    <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
    Personal Email</a>.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed you are not defining z-index for any of these elements. Try modifiying your css on this element and let me know if this is the solution you are looking for:

```
#first{
    top:0;
    z-index: 9998;
}
#header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

here is a screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OMIw.png)

Comment: z-index lets you order your layers and define what should be on top of what. Maybe I'm not understanding the problem you are trying to solve. I'll add this in a snippet.

Comment: Please take a look at the snippet @AbdullahZareaa and let me know if this is what you were looking after.

Comment: yeah, the #nav is not covering the whole area

Comment: I added a 100% width to #nav so it can take the whole width.  Please take a look now.  I will need some tweaking in order to look pixel perfect but that's the idea.  Notice that I added a margin top to #p so it will start below that #header and not underneath.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav> <!-- Dummy nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> <!-- Real nav bar -->
    <!-- Nav bar details -->
</nav>
```

This is the bootstrap class that will solve your problem. Use it as it is

For further info do read

> Blockquote
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I wan to know how to build one on my own, then, later I can use bootstrap also I want to know to prevent elements from overlapping

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlanSimpsonMe/Responsive_Nav_Bar/master/index.html Please check this code, I now understand what you asked for.